# html2canvas not support transform property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html2canvas

I build an image editor in javascript for my customer and we issue one huge problem. When we want to generate image where is some text rotated, canvas not generate full image with all contents over background.

Here is example:

[image]

When I click on save button I get empty background like this:

[image]

On other way, when I just add content and NOT do rotation, transform not exists in CSS, I can change color of text, change font, change background and all will look nice like on this example:

[image]

Result is perfect:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function generateImage(canvas, width){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.width = width;
    img.height = (img.width / ( 16 / 9 ));
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    img.align = 'middle';
    img.class = 'img-responsive';
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.maxWidth = width;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

html2canvas($this, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        generateImage(canvas, ($this.width()+2));
    },
    width: $this.width()+2,
    height: $this.height()+2
});
```

The main question is:

Is there a way to add in canvas CSS transition support to can render proper full image or some 3D canvas drawing which work properly?

Comment: There is an issue with how html2canvas is clipping the transformed elements. Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1138, is your application only client side or you have server side also? if you do have server side, I use phantomJS and webshot with my nodejs applications, but I think there is enough libraries and tools doing so for all major server side languages.

Comment: Yeah. I just trying test library form https://jsfiddle.net/jjarrpw7/ and work wierd. I will try phantomJS, that may work. Is that support jQuery? I not use node in this work. You have some working example to share? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot, it has a lot of examples, I use it to capture screenshots of rendered element on my application which is built with jQuery and angularJS, but take into consideration that you will have to do it on server side and not on the browser of your users.

Comment: Thanks will try.